# Same answer to the same question

Tags: discussion, support, flags, low-quality-posts

I'm talking specifically about [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59553714/5675325).

After seeing it, I flagged as Very Low Quality because all it says is what we can read in the [already accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36123324/5675325) and wrote a comment saying

> Hi Amit Buyo, welcome. How is that different from Avinash Raj's
>   answer?

The flag wasn't accepted and the explanation said

> declined - flags should not be used to indicate technical
>   inaccuracies, or an altogether wrong answer

This explanation of the flag assumes I mentioned technical inaccuracies, or an altogether wrong answer. Yet, while flagging, VLQ we can read

> This answer has severe formatting or content problems. This answer is
>   unlikely to be salvageable through editing, and might need to be
>   removed.

I interpreted using the same content as a severe content problem and, at my sight, it would make sense to remove it (so the rest of VLQ flag information seemed to give grounds to this decision).

Comment: VLQ is for gibberish, not for any low quality answer. Emphasis on **very**.

Comment: I would (possibly) raise a custom mod flag on that, starting the "reason" text with a big, bold, "PLAGIARISM" and then going on to point out the other (copied) answer.

Comment: @AdrianMole I'm not sure if it's plagiarism in that sense of the word. It's not a verbatim copy.

Comment: @JAD The code is an *exact* copy, but I see what you mean. But, with all custom-mod flags, it's best to get your main point across fast and strong: "Start with a Bang, finish with a Whisper," is how we were taught back at school. This will help mods pick out the flags they feel need attention.

Comment: @yivi this question is two folded. While that one you mention targets one of the problems, leaves to answer how then i should proceed. The current answer addresses all concerns.

Comment: That's how I'm gonna proceed from now onwards @AdrianMole 

Comment: don't forget to downvote answers that add no value.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

SO gets several hundred flags *a day*. SO mods presumably need to go through dozens daily, if not hundreds. So there is very little time to devote to each flag. As a result, when the mod saw your VLQ flag, they must have looked at the answer, saw nothing wrong with it and declined your flag.

When the issue with a post isn't immediately obvious just by looking at the post (in this case, you had to also see the other answer to understand what was wrong), you should use custom flags and explain what the issue is so the mod who handles your flag can understand.

---

*Disclaimer: I am not a mod on SO, but I am a moderator on another site and an ex-moderator on two more, so I do have some experience with the flag handling interface.*

Comment: I am a mod on SO, and I endorse this message.